# How many anagrams there are in a sentence in C

Tags: c

I was asked to write a code that returns the maximum number of anagrams (word made by transposing the letters of another word like the word “secure” is an anagram of “rescue.”).
This is what I did:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
char text[1000], angrm1[1000], angrm2[1000];
int i, j, k, count = 1, flag = 0, temp, size = 0, q = 1, counter = 0, max = 0;
char**point;

printf_s("Please enter the sentence, and then press Enter:\n");
gets(text);

strcpy_s(angrm1, 1000, text);
j = 1; i = 0;

for (i = 0; i < strlen(angrm1); i = k + 2) {

        for (k = i; angrm1[k + 1] != ' '&&angrm1[k + 1]!=0; k++) {
            if (angrm1[i] > angrm1[i + 1]) {
                temp = angrm1[k];
                angrm1[k] = angrm1[k + 1];
                angrm1[k + 1] = temp;

            }
        }
```

> Blockquote Arrange the words

```
     size = strlen(angrm1);
}
for (i = 0; angrm1[i] != 0; i++)
{
    if (angrm1[i] == ' ')
    {
        angrm1[i] = 0;
        count++;
    }
}

point = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*count);
for (i = 0; i < (size - 1); i++)
{
    if (angrm1[i] == 0)
    {
        point[q] = &point[i + 1];
        q++;
    }
}
for (i = 0; i < counter; i++)
{
    for (q = i + 1; q < counter; q++)
    {
        if (point[q] == 0 || point[i] == 0)
            continue;
        if (!strcmp(point[q], point[i]))
        {
            counter++;
            point[q] = 0;
        }
    }
    if (max < counter)
        max = counter;
    counter = 0;
}
printf_s("The maximum  (not yet) number of anagram words in this sentence is %d", &max);
}
```

The first part works (in my opinion).
But when I check with the debugger, it skips the loop and I get junk.
Can someone please help me by pointing to the problem, and explaining how to fix it?

Comment: `counter` initialized to 0 so `i < counter` fails, thus skipping the loop.

Comment: Never use `gets`, its obsolete and removed from C 11 standard. Use the alternative `fgets` instead. And why are you returning a cast from `malloc`?